# Using DispatcherTimer Frequently update to GUI on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an problem that wp8.1 to frequently updating to GUI.
I am in a situation that I will receive a update from a async task in a unspecified time, then I need to update GUI, the dispatcherTimer work good, but how can I adjust it in my situation and how do I know if the update is completed before I stop it?(that I dont know in what time I will receive the update, feels it should be a eventhandler like. I have tried using the Dispatcher to update those binded properties, but it failed somehow in a more frequently update situation)?
Thank alot!

```
        private async void heartRateMeasurement_DataChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
            Random r = new Random();
            var nummer = r.Next(0, 300);
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                heartRadioQueue.Enqueue(nummer);
            }
    }

dispatcherTimer.TickTask = () => 
                {
                    UpdateGUI();
                };
        private void UpdateGUI()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            int ratio;
            if (heartRadioQueue.TryDequeue(out ratio))
            {
                this.BeatPerMinute.Text = ratio.ToString();
                this.heartRateMonitorViewModel.addHeartRatio(Convert.ToUInt16(ratio));
                //outputDataChart.PlotChart(this.heartRateMonitorViewModel.HeartRatio.ToArray());
            }
            //return Task.FromResult()
        }
    }

private ObservableCollection<BeatPerMinuteLineChart> heartRatio = new ObservableCollection<BeatPerMinuteLineChart>() { new BeatPerMinuteLineChart(0, 0) };
        public ObservableCollection<BeatPerMinuteLineChart> HeartRatio 
        {
            get 
            {
                return heartRatio; //bind to linechart
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null && value.Count() > 0)
                {
                  heartRatio = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private int count = 1;
        public void addHeartRatio(ushort beatPerMinute) 
        {
             heartRatio.Add(new BeatPerMinuteLineChart(count++, beatPerMinute));
        }
```

Comment: What kind of updates are you performing?  Are the standard change notification mechanisms insufficient?  e.g., `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged`, etc.  Can you not simply update your view model with the new data and let the UI update through bindings?

Comment: the update will happened approximate 2 sec

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: Hey Mike, I am having it binded on a viewmodel and i update those properties by using dispatch, thing is it will stop re acting after a while, i dont know why

Comment: if you have an update every 2 sec @Jovirus is right, standard way should do the job. If you have an event hundreds of times per minute. It might hurt performance. In that case you could queue them in an ConcurrentQueue and TryDequeue them in you DispatcherTimer.

Comment: I wonder if one of the issues is that it's `async void`, so they're not necessarily occurring in-order, as the method continues before the dispatched call is made. I think @CyprienAutexier's suggestion of making a queue is a good idea if this is the case.

Comment: @NateDiamond I am now add a heartRadioQueue.Enqueue(nummer) in the listener and running a dispatchTime to display on GUI(a binded ObserCollec.) and dequeue it and I took away the async and await. it still fails. The difficult thing is there are no exceptions throw out, which give me no clue, what is actually failing.

Comment: If it's a UI error it may not throw exceptions that you can catch. Are you monitoring the debug output? When you debug and put breakpoints all throughout the process, does it hit any of them?

Comment: Maybe you should share the code with the queue and the exception details.

Comment: Hey @NateDiamond the debug output is giving a information that the listener thread has existed with code 0. Is there any way to know why this is exited? I guess the Intellitrace tool is not support WP .

Comment: @CyprienAutexier hey now I have update the simple version of this code.

Comment: The code works fine if I just update the textblock"this.BeatPerMinute.Text". But once when I start to update the ObservableCollection which is binded to a line chart, thing goes wrong the listener thread will end.

Comment: Make sure you're updating PropertyChanged on the UI thread.

Comment: @NateDiamond I think the ObserCollect. its self implement the INotificationPropertyChange

Comment: This is true. If you change something in an ObservableCollection, it notifies CollectionChanged. If you do this not on the UI thread, it will still attempt to notify. Make sure you make changes to the collection on the UI thread.

Comment: @NateDiamond yes, dispatcherTimer is running on UI thread.strange thing is that, it updates some time, but after a while it stopped.

Comment: It looks like it used to be async. Further, your `heartRateMeasurement_DataChanged` is `async void`. I am wondering if you are making an async call when adding it to the queue that is causing the issue. We'll need to see the `addHeartRatio` code.

Comment: @NateDiamond updated. I have removed the async, that not matters since it is a event handler. and the ConcurrentQueue is a static glodal parameter.